# RecyclerView starts in the middle when not using wrap_content

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a `RecyclerView` inside of a `ConstraintLayout`, I need to set the height to 0dp so that it respects its constraints and doesn't go under the other views. But once the list is loaded, its set to the middle of the list. 
If I set the height to `wrap_content`, the issue is fixed, but then it doesn't look right because it fills the screen and it goes under the other views
I even tried wrapping the RV in a `FrameLayout`, so that I can set my RV to wrap content and still have it respect the constraints, but that took me to issue one (loads in the middle).

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <view above>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="view above"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="view below"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
  <view below>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

and my code for setting up the RV:

```
with(recyclerView){
  setHasFixedSize(true)
  overScrollMode = View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER
  setLayoutManager(LinearLayoutManager(context).apply { stackFromEnd = true })
  setAdapter(adapter)
  setItemAnimator(itemAnimator)
}
```

I know I can use `scrollToPosition()`, but then when there are images I'm the list, I have to wait till they are all loaded before I call it, and this takes a few seconds and it shows up as stutter to the user.

*UPDATE* I was setting the height to 0dp initially, which would cause the list to start off scrolled to the middle. Later I set it to wrap_content and match_parent which would cause the list to span the whole width or window and overlap the other views in the container.

Comment: "But once the list is loaded, its set to the middle of the list." I don't get that. Also, could yo provide some images of what is happening now if you put the height equals to 0 and what happens when you set it to wrap content instead ?

Comment: make the height of your recyclerview 0dp..

Comment: @dglozano the list would start off being scrolled to the middle

Answer (score 4):

Turns out that if you set the RV (RecyclerView) height to 0dp (aka match constraint), you also have to set the width to 0dp as well. This is an android bug.

this is the code that fixed it:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messagesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="[view above]"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="[view below]"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice:

```
stackFromEnd = true
```

When stackFromEnd is true the list fills its content starting from the bottom of the view.

Answer (score 0):

Just set your **recyclerview height to 0dp**.

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <view above>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="view above"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="view below"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
  <view below>
</ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have set your constraints to top and bottom of parent view, So the view will stretch to top and bottom. You need to set your constraints as below

```
<ConstraintLayout>
  <view above>
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messagesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/your_above_view_id"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/your_below_view_id"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
  <view below>
</ConstraintLayout>
```